# Showing a cross-hair programatically in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Has anyone been able to successfully render a cross-hair programatically in Highcharts?

I have a visualization playing an animation through time and I would like to co-relate the position on the chart via the crosshair. I find that visual cue better than selecting the point on a series. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Highcharts has something called a cross-hair, I guess what I'm looking for is a plot line.

I've found [documentation here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines) and an [example scenario](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine)

EDIT: I've also noticed that marker.enabled must be set to false or the plot line doesn't show.